# Passing a key in object as function argument in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, object

I'm going to write a function in Javascript. It will process by passing a key.

```
// generate by coffeescript

var get_key, obj;

obj = [
  { name: 'Ape', sales: 100, location: 'US' },
  { name: 'Bob', sales: 200, location: 'UK' },
  { name: 'Cat', sales: 120, location: 'Hell' }
];

// What I want to do: (of cause it is wrong)

get_key = function(obj, key) {
  var item, value_arr, _i, _len;
  value_arr = [];
  for (_i = 0, _len = obj.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    item = obj[_i];
    value_arr.push(obj.key);
  }
  return value_arr; // return array containing all values of key in object
};

alert(get_key(obj, 'sales')); // expect return 100,200,120
```

Problem is: how to pass the 'key'?

p.s. I even don't know any keyword to search in this matter (bad English). So I can't find any answer in StackOverflow and Google. Please give some tips to ask correctly.

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var get_key, obj;

obj = [
  { name: 'Ape', sales: 100, location: 'US' },
  { name: 'Bob', sales: 200, location: 'UK' },
  { name: 'Cat', sales: 120, location: 'Hell' }
];

// What I want to do: (of cause it is wrong)

get_key = function(obj, key) {
  var item, value_arr, _i, _len;
  value_arr = [];
  for (_i = 0, _len = obj.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    item = obj[_i];
    if (key in item){
        value_arr.push(item[key]);
    }
  }
  return value_arr; // return array containing all values of key in object
};

alert(get_key(obj, 'sales')); // expect return 100,200,120
```

`item` is the object with the key you're looking for so change `value_arr.push(obj.key);` to `value_arr.push(item[key]);`, you have to use `[]` notation to access an objects property via a variable, also added a check to see if the item has a property `key` before adding to the array.

Comment: Adding a check is smart. Thanks for reminding! I tested using Coffeescript: http://codepen.io/Edditoria/pen/bBHtw

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_key(arr, key) {
    return arr.map(function(el) {
        return el[key];
    });
}
```

If need to support old browsers, you need to add the map function to Array ([check here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)).

Comment: sorry, but I don't understand el[key] (el not defined). Would you please explain?

Comment: @Edditoria `el` is the parameter of the callback function, is each element of the array.

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = [
    {
    name: 'Ape',
    sales: 100,
    location: 'US'},
{
    name: 'Bob',
    sales: 200,
    location: 'UK'},
{
    name: 'Cat',
    sales: 120,
    location: 'Hell'}
];

get_key = function(obj, key) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        /*
         *  Here, obj[i] gives the object e.g: 
         * { name: 'Ape', sales: 100, location: 'US' }...
         * 
         * and obj[i][key] give the value of corresponding key e.g:
         * 100, 200... (suppose for: sales) 
         */

        result.push(obj[i][key]);
    }
    return result;
};

alert(get_key(obj, 'sales').join(',')); ​
```

***[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/bUQmz/3/)***

---

### In your code

just change the line

```
item = obj[_i];
value_arr.push(obj.key);// this line
```

to

```
 value_arr.push(item[key]);
```

Comment: Thanks!! It works! I put it in Codepen.io using Coffeescript (I use it in daily life) http://codepen.io/Edditoria/full/bBHtw